# HttpOnly cookie will not delete

Tags: php, node.js, cookies, httponly

I am setting an httpOnly cookie via php:

```
setcookie("AuthCookie", $result, time()+60*60*24, '/', "page.io", FALSE, TRUE);
```

This is called via a jQuery ajax call:

```
request = $.ajax({
            url: "http://page.io/login.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: jsonData,
            complete: function(r){
              if (r.status == 200) {
                 window.location = 'http://beta.page.io/';
              }
            }
          });
```

login.php makes the setcookie call then jquery redirects to beta.page.io.

The httponly cookie is present on page.io. It is able to be deleted via clearing cache and data on firefox.

There is an old httponly cookie on beta.page.io. Clearing cache and data on firefox does not remove this cookie. The call to setcookie will append this cookie with another "AuthCookie".

```
setcookie("AuthCookie", $result, time()-10, '/', "page.io", FALSE, TRUE);
```

does not remove the cookie either. beta.page.io is an angular app running on a nodejs server.

How do I remove this cookie? have been working on this for several days with no solution.

Answer (score 0):

To remove cookie from subdomain, call simply:

```
setcookie('AuthCookie', '', time()-3600, '/', 'beta.page.io');
```

It is not necessary to repeat $secure or $httponly parameters and cookie will be deleted.
But it must be run on the subdomain or sub-subdomain itself - run command on **beta.page.io** or www.beta.page.io, but **not** on **page.io**.